# Asus M2NSLI Deluxe dedicated SATA RAID1 port?

Tags: motherboard, bios, raid

having a few problems with my mobo.
There are 6 standard ports and 1 dedicated sata port for raid1 (or so manual says)
I've gone through the BIOS and searched google but can't find any useful info :(

The raid menu doesn't show the raid1 port hard disk :S

Anyone try this before? or know how I can activate sata port 0 to be mirrored with this dedicated raid1 port?

EDIT:
I've just found

> http://support.asus.com/FAQ/detail.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=M2N-SLI%20Deluxe&p=1&s=24&os=&hashedid=GKRBz6QxQEWm2W58&no=58074876-8D15-5510-A883-B7A52B014AD3

Mentions:

> Solution
>   Please simply connect one HDD to the internal SATA_RAID (or SATA_RAID1, depending on the labeling of your motherboard), and another one at ESATA (which is located at rear I/O panel), then follow instructions in your user's manual to construct RAID.
>
> Note1: The above statement does not effect the RAID feature of other controller or southbridge on this motherboard.
>   Note2: ESATA is the SATA port at the back I/O.

Does the imply that I can't connect a hdd to the normal sata port 0 and another one to the dedicated raid 1 port? :(

Answer (score 0):

There are two RAID controllers on that board;  an nVidia one and a JMicron one.

From that board's manual ([available here](http://dlsvr03.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/socketAM2/M2N-SLI%20Deluxe/e2651_m2n-sli_deluxe.pdf)) on page 18:

nVidia Controller:

> The nVidia nForce 570 SLI chipset allows RAID 0, RAID 1, RAID 0+1, RAID 5 and JBOD configuration for six SATA 3.0 Gb/s connectors. See page 2-25.

JMicron Controller:

> The JMicron JMB363 controller supports two additional Serial ATA 3.0 Gb/s connectors (one at mid-board and one on the rear panel) and allows RAID 0, RAID 1 and JBOD configurations on these ports.  See page 2-26 for details.

So you should be able to use the 6 ports that aren't marked as 'SATA_RAID' in conjunction with the 'onboard nVidia MediaShield' controller to get an array built using those ports.

They also have a caveat (page 2-25): "The RAID function of these connectors is set to *[Disabled]* by default.  If you intend to create a SATA RAID using these connecotrs, enable the **RAID Enabled** item in the SATA configuration sub-menu in the BIOS."